# Using session command from a cron job (linux)

Tags: linux, cron, command, session

I need to be able to start a named "session" from within a cron job and run a job within that named session. The job I need to run MAY cause my appliance to not run properly if problem exist and I need to be able to reattach to the named session created if needed/to close it later. Does anyone have any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [TMUX](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) are probably your best options.  The general concept of both is pretty similar to a tabbed window manager, but they're both for terminal usage, and you can detach from a session and re-attach later.  I'm not quite certain about the syntax needed for TMUX, but for screen the command you want is:

```
screen -D -n -s <name> <command>
```

Replace `<name>` with the name of the session, and `<command>` with the command to run.  YOu can then re-attach to the session with:

```
screen -D -r <name>
```

The only caveat is that yuu have to be running as the same user when you try to reattach that the session was started as (you can *technically* reattach to other users sessions, but it's a bit more complicated).

Comment: hmmmm, so if it runs in a cron job it will not run as "me" so when I reattach I'd have to do the "more complicated" method. Thanks for the help, I'll test. You don't want to leave some more complicated help with the reattach do you?

Comment: Simply log in as the user who owns the cron job and run the same command to reattach.  (n. b. I usually use `screen -x` rather than `screen -r` as I often use multiclient sessions and `-x` is a superset of `-r` in that it will not fail if there is still a `screen` client attached.)

Comment: You don't even have to log in technically, you can also use a tool like `sudo` to switch to the appropriate UID (though I'm pretty sure `su` won't work for this because it doesn't reset the environment properly).  If you absolutely can't run `screen -r` or `screen -x` as that user, you can also prefix the session name with that user's name followed by a `/`, but I've had issues in the past with that not working reliably.